# Date comparisons in jpa queries in Play Framework

Tags: jpa, playframework

I have a model that includes a java.utils.Date object. I need to query against that model to find events that are scheduled before and after the current time. My current code:
`List<Event> pastEvents = Event.find("select e from Event e where e.time < TIME").fetch(4);`
returns zero results. When I change the query to > TIME it returns zero results but = TIME returns all results.

Using < and > with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP gives me incorrect results as some events that are in the future show as < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP. What should I compare my Date object to to return correct results?

Answer (score 1):

the correct query was "select e from Event e where e.time < CURRENT_TIME"